# Пуля в 3D вид сверху

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня 3д сцена, вид сверху. Нужно сделать чтобы, при нажатии мышки появлялась пуля и летела в направление места нажатия курсора и в заданной плоскости. Не вверх, не вниз. Строго прямо в направление клика.Вопрос один.
Как реализовать полет пули и ее движения? Пробовал задать силу при создании, но в 3д она просто падает из за гравитации, если гравитацию отключить, силы не действуют.

Comment: Двигай через transform и выставлять константу положения нужной плоскости, например если строго на высоте 5, то y=5

Comment: Насколько я знаю, при установке `gravityscale = 0` для данного объекта, на него перестает действовать только гравитация. Остальные силы действуют так как и раньше.

Comment: Поддерживаю этого бандита из Сталкера.

Answer (score 0):

Я двигаю при помощи `transform.Translate(Vector3);`
А чтобы еще и реалистично было, можно бы и замедление пули в атмосфере сделать.Это легко.

```
Vector3 npos;
public float drag; //степень замедления
public float spd; //начальная скорость пули
void Update(){
     if(spd > 0){
          spd -= drag * Time.deltaTime; //каждую секунду spd будет уменьшаться на drag
          npos = new Vector3(0, 0, spd); //подбирать вручную, рассчитываю на то что ось z-продольная ось пули
          transform.Translate(npos);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Через transform.Translate можно двигать пулю, что бы двигалась в сторону курсора - надо узнать Input.mousePosition и повернуть обьект в сторону курсора. Вроде бы была такая функция, возможно это LookAt или как-то так.